# Cannot convert from 'ref System.Array' to 'ref TBApp.CompanyStruct'

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am trying to implement this particular function but the issue is that it shows an error. Trying to implement an array input as a reference object but doesn't allow that conversion.

```
public short ListForPolicyType(ref Array cListForPolicyType)
    {
        return _adapted.ListForPolicyType(ref cListForPolicyType);
    }
```

Above is the .NET adapter which uses the VB extracted interface.

```
ListForPolicyType(ByRef cListForPolicyType() As CompanyListStruct) As Short
```

Above is the interface with non-implemented functions.

> Error: "cannot convert from 'ref System.Array' to 'ref TBApp.CompanyListStruct[]'

Comment: My Visual Basic isn't great, but it seems like that C# function needs to take `ref CompanyListStruct[]` as a parameter, instead of just an `Array`.

Comment: Beleave the error message: You are trying to convert a System.Array (1-dimensional, multi-dimensional, jagged, aligned whatever) into a ```TBApp.CompanyListStruct[]``` which of course the compiler complains about. If the given array _is_ a ```TBApp.CompanyListStruct[]```, then you can cast it ```CType(cListForPolicyType, TBApp.CompanyListStruct()```, otherwise implement the conversion logic. Why do you return a ```Short``` and not the result? Looks more C++ than VB to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public short ListForPolicyType(ref CompanyListStruct[] cListForPolicyType)
{
    return _adapted.ListForPolicyType(ref cListForPolicyType);
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the change you made was?

Answer (score 1):

In your VB, you pass in a 1 dimensional array of CompanyListStruct by reference.

```vb
Public Function ListForPolicyType(ByRef cListForPolicyType() As CompanyListStruct) As Short
```

This is how you would do it in c#

```cs
public short ListForPolicyType(ref CompanyListStruct[] cListForPolicyType)
{
    return _adapted.ListForPolicyType(ref cListForPolicyType);
}
```

See the syntax for a C# array [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/).

By the way, the [ByRef](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/byref) in VB.NET corresponds to both [ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref) and [out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier) keywords in C#. But judging by the usage of your `cListForPolicyType` variable, it looks like you want to use `ref`.